# WSUS patch segregation

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, wsus

how do i white list and black list MS patches as i need to install it on my client servers. We don't have the resources/test bench  to test each patch against our builds. what is the best way to segregated these patches and when should i start these process every month? please help

Answer (score 2):

You install a WSUS Server, and use the WSUS Server to "approve" updates for installation (effectively whitelisting them).

Comment: +1. It ain't rocket science